# python - assign letter of the alphabet to each value in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of values in a for loop. e.g. `myList = [1,5,7,3]` which I am using to create a bar chart (using google charts)

I want to label each value with a letter of the alphabet (A-Z) e.g. A = 1, B = 5, C = 7, D = 3

What is the best way to do this running through a for loop

e.g.

```
for x in myList:
    x.label = LETTER OF THE ALPHABET
```

The list can be any length in size so wont always be just A to D

EDIT

myList is a list of objects not numbers as I have put in example above.  Each object will have a title attached to it (could be numbers, text letters etc.), however these titles are quite long so mess things up when displaying them on Google charts.  Therefore on the chart I was going to label the chart with letters going A, B, C, ....to the lenth of the myList, then having a key on the chart cross referencing the letters on the chart with the actual titles.  The length of myList is more than likely going to be less than 10 so there would be no worries about running of of letters.

Hope this clears things up a little

Comment: What behaviour do you want if the length of the list is more than the length of the alphabet?

Comment: I think you also need to define the types you hold in the list. In your example you have a list of `ints`, and you cannot add attributes to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import string
for i, x in enumerate(myList):
    x.label = string.uppercase[i]
```

This will of course fail if `len(myList) > 26`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to go on like ..., Y, Z, AA, AB ,... you can use itertools.product:

```
import string
import itertools

def product_gen(n):
    for r in itertools.count(1):
        for i in itertools.product(n, repeat=r):
            yield "".join(i)

mylist=list(range(35))

for value, label in zip(mylist, product_gen(string.ascii_uppercase)):
    print(value, label)
#   value.label = label
```

Part of output:

```
23 X
24 Y
25 Z
26 AA
27 AB
28 AC
29 AD
```

Comment: Perhaps useless for the OP, but generally speaking a very nice snippet that could come in handy some day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

myList = [1, 5, 7, 3]
labels = [string.uppercase[x+1] for x in myList]
# ['C', 'G', 'I', 'E']
```

Comment: You tell me. It's your question.

Comment: @John: No-one is going to try it for you. Why don't you type it into your python interpreter and find out for yourself?

Comment: @Matt: I don't think this is what the OP intended. The way I read it, he wants the indices of the list (dict) to be ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] instead of [1], [2], [3].

Comment: Impossible to know what OP intended.

Comment: @Matt: this was more of a statement than a question as I assume it would error since there are not 342 letters of the alphabet.  The question I posted was worded pretty badly so I've updated it and hopefully it should make more sence now.

Comment: @John yes, your clarification significantly improves the quality of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    x.label = chr(i+65)
```

More on the function [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr).

Comment: This will fail with ValueError for i > 190. The modulus operator % can be used to restrict the characters to, for instance, uppercase letters.

Comment: @jforberg: fair enough, I'll edit as soon as the OP clarifies what behavior does he want for the these cases.

Comment: I meant no criticism, and I know you saw it as well. I just wanted to point it out :)

Comment: @jforberg: No offense take really, maybe that came out wrong! I saw it exactly the way you intended, and a clarification was needed! So thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
charValue = 65
for x in myList:
  x.label = chr(charValue)
  charValue++
```

Be careful if your list is longer than 26 characters

Answer (score 1):

First, if `myList` is a list of integers, then,

```
for x in myList:
    x.label = LETTER OF THE ALPHABET
```

won't work, since `int` has no attribute `label`. You could loop over `myList` and store the labels in a list (here: `pairs`):

```
import string

pairs = []
for i, x in enumerate(myList):
    label = string.letters(i) # will work for i < 52 !!
    pairs.append( (label, x) )

# pairs is now a list of (label, value) pairs
```

If you need more than 52 labels, you can use some random string generating function, like this one:

```
import random

def rstring(length=4):
    return ''.join([ random.choice(string.uppercase) for x in range(length) ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I like list comprehensions, I'd do it like this:

```
[(i, chr(x+65)) for x, i in enumerate([1, 5, 7, 3])]
```

Which results in:

```
[(1, 'A'), (5, 'B'), (7, 'C'), (3, 'D')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

for val in zip(myList, string.uppercase):
    val[0].label = val[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this:

```
from string import uppercase

res = ((x , uppercase[i%26]*(i//26+1)) for i,x in enumerate(inputList))
```

Or you can use something like this - note that this is just an idea how to deal with long lists not the solution:

```
from string import uppercase
res = ((x , uppercase[i%26] + uppercase[i/26]) for i,x in enumerate(inputList))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a dictionary, where each of your values are keyed to a letter of the alphabet? In that case, you can do:

```
from string import lowercase as letters

values = [1, 23, 3544, 23]
mydict = {}
for (let, val) in zip(letters, values):
    mydict[let] = val

<<< mydict == {'a': 1, 'c': 23, 'b': 3544, 'd': 23}

<<< mydict['a'] == 1
```

You'll have to add additional logic if you need to handle lists longer than the alphabet.